# Proof that function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

**Question:**
Prove that $x+\frac x{x+1}$ is uniformly continuous in $(1,\infty)$:

**My solution:**
We need to find a $\delta$ that satisfies the criterion for uniform continuity.

- Let $\varepsilon >0 ,   x,y>1 $
- We pick $\delta = \frac 4{5\varepsilon}$ so if $|x-y|<\delta$
- $\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|x+\frac x{x+1} + y + \frac y{y+1}\right| \le $(triangle inequality) 
  $ |x-y|+\left|\frac x{x+1}-\frac y{y+1}\right| =$
  $ |x-y|+\left|\frac {x-y}{(x+1)(y+1)}\right| \le$
  $ \delta + \frac \delta{(x+1)(y+1)} \le  $ (because $x,y>1$)
  $ \delta + \frac \delta{4} =\frac 54 \delta = \varepsilon $

I wanted to verify the correctness of this as it took a long time to do it, and it's a first timer for me :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct!
 
You could also use a result which says that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $F\subseteq \mathbb R$ if $f'(x)$ is bounded on $F$.

Comment: it's fun to be correct once on a freshmen year :-)